# Space in elements of GridLayout Python Kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

i'm writing a simple python Kivy GUI for read the content of files selected by the user. The problem i have, is a space not wanted in elements of a inner GridLayout, following the screen of Gui.

## Output of code

[image: Img01 - Output of code]

As you can see, there are two rectangular space that i didn't declared, the relative code written in .kv file is:

```
GridLayout:
        id: grid_1_level_one
        cols: 1
        rows: 3
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_1_level_two
            cols: 1
            rows: 1
            height: 100
            size_hint_y: None
            Label:
                id: title_parameters_view
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
                text: "Parameters"
                size: self.texture_size
        GridLayout:
            id: grid_2_level_two
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            #size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            FileChooserListView:
                id: visualize_file_chooser_variables
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#413FBF')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                on_selection: root.selected_file(*args)
            RstDocument:
                id: document_parameter_viewer

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 1
            height: 30
            size_hint_y: None
            Button:
                id: button_home_visualize
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
                text: "Turn to home"
                size: self.texture_size
                on_press: root.go_to_home()
```

Do you know some trick to avoid this solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to decrease the height (`self.y - 30`) of the *FileChooserListView* by the height of the button / last GridLayout (`height: 30`).

## Snippets

```
        FileChooserListView:
            id: visualize_file_chooser_variables
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#413FBF')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.x, self.y - 30
                    size: self.size
            on_selection: root.selected_file(*args)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]